# Table view cell - autolayout

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, constraints, cell

I'm having some issues with the autolayout.
Here's a screenshot:

[image: screen]

left: original view from my storyboard ; right: preview

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have a horizontal spacing constraint between statt and Fach labels. You can see constraints better from the Document Outline ( Editor > Show Document Outline)

Even if you add the constraint, the layout seems a bit tight.

Comment: fixed but that doesnt solve my problem... the labels arent spaced equally

Comment: You need to post more information, e.g. show a screenshot of Document Outline with all the constraints visible.